# How to add any command in Environment Variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a variable

```
 PVM_RSH=/usr/bin/ssh
```

I want to add a flag `-v` to check how ssh works, step by step.

For that I run a command `PVM_RSH="/usr/bin/ssh -v "`.

But it shows

**Error - File /usr/bon/ssh -v Not Found!**

Help me how can I overcome from this error.

Comment: How do you run the command?

Comment: Actually I want to add slaves for PVM. I made ssh passwordless connection. But when I do job it shows some error, slaves not do their job, so for that I want to check how master connects with slave.

Comment: is it just a typo or did you write *bon* instead of *bin*?

Comment: @Davide Berra: No there is no such error.

Comment: then fix the content of your post please

Comment: I didn't understand what you said?

Comment: RSH is not ROOT. Are you setting the correct variable?

Comment: Sorry, check again the question, PVM_RSH is misplaced by PVM_ROOT

Comment: how r u trying to run it ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder you want to do an Alias or Define that in the variable

```
  1. alias something='unix command with options'
```

or

1. Set the varaible which can be done in by using "`"

for example :

```
  PVM_ROOT=`some command whose output u want to set`
  For example : PVM_ROOT=`cat file | wc -l` --gives the count of number of lines
```

Also in UNIX , for SSH there is no -v option

Since i dont you LINUX this is what you are trying to do :

```
$a="ftp -i"

 $ echo $a
 ftp -i
 $ `echo $a`
 ftp>
```

Comment: I don't know about UNIX, but in Linux (check the tags) `-v` means "verbose".

Comment: PVM_ROOT="/usr/bin/ssh -v " just defines a variable . its a literal string how you will you execute it ? However this works (added in answer )

Answer (score 0):

PVM_RSH="/usr/bin/ssh -v "

To run the command the contents of the variable PVM_RSH must output for the shell to interpret.
so-:

**$PVM_RSH**